# Simple hello world segfaults in VSCode Run C/C++ file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, intellisense, vscode-debugger

I am trying to run a simple Hello World program in VSCode, but it is crashing with a segmentation fault. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

When I click Run C/C++ File, I get this output in the Debug Console:

```
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ff7cf5b145d in main ()
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff49f3c226 in ?? () from C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
```

I have tried solutions like updating VSCode and C++ extensions, restarting, checking launch config, but nothing has resolved the issue so far.

Can someone please help me understand and fix this segfault when running a simple C++ program in VSCode?

**EDIT:** It looks like the debugger is trying to load symbols from `C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\`. I am not sure why the debugger is loading symbols from this path. I have not included it anywhere in the JSON configurations.

**EDIT:** Actually, this problem occurred when I was working on my OpenGL assignment. A simple `cout` caused the whole program to crash even before it ran properly. I have tried to include a minimum reproducible example here.

---

Here are the JSON configurations in `.vscode` folder:

launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": ["4"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
        
 
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-lfreeglut",
                "-lglew32",
                "-lopengl32",
                "-lglu32"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: As this is one of the many questions concerning VS-Code and Windows, I have to ask this -- have you considered using Visual Studio 2022 Community Editition?  It seems there are at least 5 to 10 questions per-day of new C++ programmers (on Windows) having problems using VS-Code and g++ as their IDE and compiler.

Comment: You're in [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). The OS found `C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll` before it found the libstdc++-6.dll that shipped with your compiler, and in spite of having the same name, they are slightly different versions..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Nope, I do most of my work in VS-Code and I am heavily dependent on the extensions. I have not faced any problem like this with any of my work except for this one. Changing the whole development environment just for a single problem is too overkill for me.

Comment: @user4581301 I have included `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/` at the top of the system environment variables table. Still, it did not fix my problem. Do you know where to change so that the OS doesn't look in the path you mentioned?

Comment: If you change the path you often have to reboot. Many tools will have the old path cached. Note that by changing the order you may have just broken your git install because now it will find the wrong DLL.

Comment: Probably just lack of novelty in the question causing the downvotes. While there is probably no 1:1 duplicate because everyone's circumstances are slightly different, this question gets asked just about every day. That said, I'm not 100% sure I'm right or I'd have done more than just comment.

Comment: What happens to git if you take `C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\ ` out of the system path rather than adding the compiler's path? In my experience the more tools you (or they) put in the path, the more likely you are to get a boot to the head like this. In my day-to-day job I have about a dozen different GCC versions for a few different maintenance projects. If any of them got into the path it would be total carnage. Try to keep the system path as close to empty as Windows and the tools will allow.

Comment: @user4581301 `C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\ `  wasn't even included in the system path before. I only included `C:\Programs\Git\cmd` since I use git bash when working in Windows.

Comment: Now you have an interesting question: "Who is pulling in  `C:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin`?" Is it Windows doing it anyway in a double super-secret system path? VS Code because of a tight alliance with Git? A plug-in? Officer Barbrady?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would prefer to use Linux full-time, but unfortunately most of my academic studies require MS Word/Powerpoint, which is holding me back from switching completely. It sucks :(

Comment: Have you followed [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)? The VS Code documentation seems quite rich, and there are guides for each of the major compilers. There are even videos, if you're that way inclined.

Comment: "_I would prefer to use Linux full-time, but unfortunately most of my academic studies require MS Word/Powerpoint, which is holding me back from switching completely. It sucks_" why not use WSL then?

Comment: @starball I am already using WSL. I tried using OpenGL within WSL but for some reason, the timer function did not work correctly there. The window does render though, so I had to do my OpenGL assignment in Windows.

Comment: @starball I do almost all of my coding projects in WSL with VSCode Remote-SSH. In the rare case of this particular assignment, I had to write and debug the code directly in Windows using VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I finally managed to solve the problem. I renamed `C:\Programs\Git\mingw64` to `C:\Programs\Git\mingw64ABC`, then compiled my program and it ran fine. Then I restored `mingw64ABC` to its original name and now everything is working correctly as expected. I am not sure whether Windows caches the symbol search paths internally somewhere, that might be the culprit. I am speculating that once the OS had a cache miss, it removed that path from the list and appended the correct search path `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/`.